# How do i write push and pops functions in a stack? In C

Tags: stack, push, stack-pointer

Professor asked to write a stack and then define the functions of push and pop in C. Hints were of using a stack pointer and an array, but it seems i can't do it properly (I didn't understand the lesson i think). Can you help me sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

In a stack, `push` adds an item to the stack. `pop` removes the last item that was added.

If you have an array, call it `a` of some length, `len`, and an index, call it `i`, then you can implement a simple stack.

```
initialize a with length len
i = 0
```

Now, to push an item, you add the item to the array at index `i`, and then increment the index. But you have to make sure you don't overflow the stack:

```
if (i >= len) {
    /* error, stack is full */
} else {
    a[i] = new_item
    i = i + 1
}
```

And to pop an item, you decrease `i` by 1, and return the value that's in the array at that position. But first you have to make sure that there's something on the stack:

```
if (i == 0) {
    /* error, stack is empty */
}
else {
    i = i - 1;
    return a[i];
}
```